# Display file based on user selected index

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm developing a webpage using jsp. I'm displaying a list of file from local disk and i want to open the correct file when clicked.
This is what i have done so far.

```
<select id="folder" name="folder">
                <option>- SELECT -</option>
                <%
                for (int i=0; i<folder.length; i++) { %>
                    <option value="<%= folder[i] %>"><%= folder[i] %></option>
                    <% }
                %>
            </select>
```

This will display folder list in a drop down. When user select a folder. Folder content will be displayed in a table.

```
    //open file in folder B
            if (s!= null && s.equals(folder[1])) {
                String subfolder2 = folder[1];
                String folderfilelist2 = dir + "\\" + subfolder2 + "\\" + "pdf";
                File completefolder2 = new File(folderfilelist2);
                completefolder2.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                File[] file_array2 = completefolder2.listFiles();
                        out.print("<table width=1200><tr>");
                        out.print("<p><th width=30><font size=\"6\">File under Company B</th></p>");
                        out.print("</tr></table>");
                        //create table 
                        out.print("<table width=1200><tr>");
                             out.print("<th width=50><b>No</b></th>");
                             out.print("<th width=400><b>File Name</b></th>");
                             out.print("<th width=200><b>Date Converted</b></th>");
                             out.print("<th width=100><b>Mark File</b></th>");
                             out.print("<th width=100><b>Download</b></th>");
                             out.print("<tr><th colspan=5><hr></th></tr>");
                        out.print("</tr></table>");
                        //list file
                        for (int i = 0; i < file_array2.length; i++) {
                             out.print("<table width=1200><tr>");
                                  out.print("<th width=50><font size=\"4\">" + (i +1 ) + "</font></th>");
                                  out.print("<th width=400><font size=\"4\"><a HREF='openfile'"+ file_array2[i].getName() + "\">" + file_array2[i].getName() + "</a></th>");
                                  out.print("<th width=200><font size=\"4\">" + df.format(new Date( file_array2[i].lastModified())) + "</font></th>");
                                  out.print("<th width=100> <input type='checkbox' name='selectedfile' value="+ file_array2[i].getName() +"\"></td>");
                                  out.print("<th width=100><a href='downloadfile'>Download</a></td>");
                             out.print("</tr></table>");
                        }
```

Onclick on the file, it will call a servlet to display the file.

```
    out.print("<th width=400><font size=\"4\"><a HREF='openfile'"+ file_array2[i].getName() + "\">" + file_array2[i].getName() + "</a></th>");
```

The 'openfile' will call on servlet.

Servlet code:

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("APPLICATION/PDF");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\""
                            + file_array1[1].getName() + "\"");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(completefolder2 + "\\" + file_array2[1].getName());

    int q;
    while( (q = fileInputStream.read()) != -1 ) {
        out.write(q);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
    out.close();
    }
```

The problem is, in servlet in can only specify one file to be displayed on web page.

How do I setup the servlet to open the selected file from the list?

Comment: Is there a problem in your code? It seems to me you ate doing things the right way.

Comment: I think the problem is in servlet part, i want the servlet to open the selected file. For now, it only open the file I specified in FileInputStream.

Comment: you can pass the name of the file to open in the href link as an url parameter, and retrieve this parameter in the servlet using request.getParameter(paramName);

Comment: i got null value when i did that

Comment: can you post the full code of your servlet?

Comment: i already did in my question.